# GitLab Shared runner, deploy spring boot microservice app to custom server

Tags: spring-boot, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment

Before i start, let me tell you that i'm newbie to Gitlab CI file :)

i'm looking to automate deployments of spring boot microservice app to custom server (a namecheap VPS).

**(I'm using the Gitlab shared runner)**

i have used jHipster ci-cd to generate the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file. Doing that, i have: build, package, release stages working.

i even could see the image repository built in Gitlab Container registery. 
What last, is the deployment. i know that i have to use a docker container to deploy it, but i don't know how.

I'm stuck in deploying the image repository to my VPS. 
(as it's my first microservice, my VPS is still new, having only java installed).

Here is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
#image: jhipster/jhipster:v6.9.0
image: openjdk:11-jdk

cache:
  key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
  paths:
    - .maven/

stages:
  - check
  - build
  #    - test
  #    - analyze
  - package
  - release
  - deploy
before_script:
  - chmod +x mvnw
  - git update-index --chmod=+x mvnw
  - export NG_CLI_ANALYTICS="false"
  - export MAVEN_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.maven

nohttp:
  stage: check
  script:
    - ./mvnw -ntp checkstyle:check -Dmaven.repo.local=$MAVEN_USER_HOME

maven-compile:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./mvnw -ntp compile -P-webpack -Dmaven.repo.local=$MAVEN_USER_HOME
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/classes/
      - target/generated-sources/
    expire_in: 1 day

#maven-test:
#    stage: test
#    script:
#        - ./mvnw -ntp verify -P-webpack -Dmaven.repo.local=$MAVEN_USER_HOME
#    artifacts:
#        reports:
#            junit: target/test-results/**/TEST-*.xml
#        paths:
#            - target/test-results
#            - target/jacoco
#        expire_in: 1 day


maven-package:
  stage: package
  script:
    - ./mvnw -ntp verify -Pprod -DskipTests -Dmaven.repo.local=$MAVEN_USER_HOME
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/*.jar
      - target/classes
    expire_in: 1 day

# Uncomment the following line to use gitlabs container registry. You need to adapt the REGISTRY_URL in case you are not using gitlab.com
docker-push:
  stage: release
  variables:
    REGISTRY_URL: registry.gitlab.com
    IMAGE_TAG: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG-$CI_COMMIT_SHA
  dependencies:
    - maven-package
  script:
    - ./mvnw -ntp compile jib:build -Pprod -Djib.to.image=$IMAGE_TAG -Djib.to.auth.username=gitlab-ci-token  -Djib.to.auth.password=$CI_BUILD_TOKEN -Dmaven.repo.local=$MAVEN_USER_HOME



docker-deploy:
  image: docker:stable-git
  stage: deploy
  script:
  when: manual
  only:
    - master
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Just to put you on track, as a macro scenario, from your deploy task script: 1) connect to your VPS 2) docker login to the registry 3) pull the image you just built, 4) docker run it. 5) logout from the registry

Comment: Could you help me further with commands? Thanks.